# Error In If Else That I cannot figure out

Tags: php

I have the following code so that before it writes the record to the database, it checks to see if there is a username that already exists.....

```
$duplicate=mysql_query("SELECT username FROM user WHERE username='" . $username . "'"); 


if ($duplicate <> $username) {
        $insertquery = mysql_query("insert into user                (username, password, lastlogin, address1, address2,             address3, email) values ('$userid', '$password', now            (),'$address1','$address2','$address3','$email')");
    //$msg = "Successfully Registered!";
    $msg = mysql_fetch_assoc($username);
  } else {

    $pass_err = "This Username Is Already In Use!";
    $msg = "This Username Is Already In Use!";
    $userid="";
    $err_flag="False";
    $dupe="";
    $numrecords=0;
}
}
```

What am I missing?  It always says it already exists, when I know it doesn't....

Comment: RTFM: [mysql_query](http://php.net/mysql_query) returns a statement **HANDLE**, not the value you're trying to retrieve. You need to first FETCH a row of data so you can get at the actual `username` value.

Comment: you need to run fetch statement against $duplicate and then compare the results of that with $username.

Comment: Add var_dump($duplicate); and var_dump($username); to see the content of $duplicate and $username. It will help you understand.

Comment: By the way, you should not be using mysql_query. Get in the habit of using prepared statements with either PDO or mysqli.

Comment: Doing this will give a race condition. You should mark the username column as unique in your table, then just do the insert without checking first. If you get a duplicate mySQL will throw an error which you check for. Safer, and only one call to the database.

Answer (score 3):

Fetch statement missing

```
$duplicate=mysql_query("SELECT username FROM user WHERE username='" . $username . "'"); 
$row=mysql_fetch_array($duplicate);

if ($row['username'] == $username) {
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After mysql query, you need to fetch the result

```
$duplicate = mysql_result($duplicate);
```